# source ~/.bashrc not working

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I very unintelligently removed everything except a single directory (`~/code/bin`) from my path on my `bashrc`.

Realizing my error, I attempted to restore the path to default with `/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`

This command ran fine, but now, when I attempt to refresh my `bashrc` with `source ~/.bashrc` , I get the following errors:

```
-bash: lesspipe: command not found
-bash: dircolors: command not found
```

Any ideas how I can fix this and get my command line back to normal? I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 on an embedded computer (I'm using picocom from my laptop to get in over serial)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The basic elements of your `PATH` should be inherited from `/etc/environment` - did you mess with that as well? In fact I don't think the default `~/.bashrc` modifies `PATH` at all.

Comment: No; I just modified the bashrc to include export PATH=~/code/bin. I'm assuming this messed up my path because when I try to run commands (cd, ls) I get command not found errors.

Comment: In that case, everything should return to normal once you log out and back in

Comment: Ah, this was the problem, thanks! I suppose logging out and back in forces the terminal to reset or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `PATH` manually:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

The `.bashrc` you restored from `/etc/skel` is a very basic `.bashrc`, with none of your customizations.

Comment: @kiwifish Rather than posting a "Thank you", please Accept my answer.